# Java ExecutorService only running 2 threads not four

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on an application that retrieves files from different URL's.

There is a TreeSet that contains the target to download. This is processed in a loop with each item being called with an ExecutorService. Here's some code:

```
private void retrieveDataFiles() {
    if (this.urlsToRetrieve.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Target URLs to retrieve: " + this.urlsToRetrieve.size());
        ExecutorService executorProcessUrls = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.urlsToRetrieve.size());//could use fixed pool based on size of urls to retrieve
        for (Entry target : this.urlsToRetrieve.entrySet()) {
            final String fileName = (String) target.getKey();
            final String url = (String) target.getValue();

            String localFile = localDirectory + File.separator + fileName;
            System.out.println(localFile);
            executorProcessUrls.submit(new WikiDumpRetriever(url, localFile));
            dumpFiles.add(localFile); 
            //TODO: figure out why only 2 files download
        }
        executorProcessUrls.shutdown();
        try {
            executorProcessUrls.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("retrieveDataFiles InterruptedException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No target URL's were retrieved");
    }
}
```

Then the WikiDumpRetriever:

```
private static class WikiDumpRetriever implements Runnable {

    private String wikiUrl;
    private String downloadTo;

    public WikiDumpRetriever(String targetUrl, String localDirectory) {
        this.downloadTo = localDirectory;
        this.wikiUrl = targetUrl;
    }

    public void downloadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HTTPCommunicationGet httpGet = new HTTPCommunicationGet(wikiUrl, "");
        httpGet.downloadFiles(downloadTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            downloadFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("WDR: FileNotFound " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("WDR: IOException " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println("WDR: URISyntaxException " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is an inner class. The TreeSet contains:

Key : Value

enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 : http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

elwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 : http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/elwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

zhwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 : http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/zhwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

hewiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 : http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/hewiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

The problem is that this process downloads 2 of the four files. I know that all four are available and I know that they can be downloaded. However, only 2 of them process at any time.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me please - what am I missing or what am I getting wrong?

Thanks
nathj07

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? what did you find?

Comment: Do all threads get executed? What exactly does not happen, the actual downloading or the writing onto the file system? Is there a limit of the OS that only 2 concurrent connections are allowed to one server at one time?

Comment: Can you download all four from a browser? Maybe the page limits you to two simultaneous download streams at a time!

Comment: Hi, thanks to everyone for stopping by and giving this some thought. I can download them all sucessfully from the browser, but I haven't tried doing it all at the same time. 
Essentially, the process downloads 2 of the fours files listed and the 2 that download are seemingly random.

Comment: Can you check the affect of the code line `executorProcessUrls.shutdown();` and is it shutting down threads/ break the execution of the treads ?

Comment: Hi, I'm away from the source code now but will definitely try moving the shutdown() on Monday. I'll keep you all posted. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like ppeterka is right. I can download only 2 at time from the browser! As soon as I try to download a 3rd I get a page returning 403 - yet if that page was the first one tried it works. Now to tweak my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ppeterka - it was a limit from the source. So, to overcome this I set the fixed thread pool size to 2. This means that only 2 files are downloaded simultaneously.

The answer then was to find the vendor imposed limit and set the thread pool:

```
ExecutorService executorProcessUrls = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

I wanted to accept an answer but couldn't seem to do it with the comments. Sorry if this was the wrong way to do it.

Thanks for all the pointers - the 'group think' really helped solve this for me.